# PHP unserialize error

Tags: php, serialization, syntax-error

I am getting the following error :-

> Message: unserialize() function.unserialize: Error at offset 65517 of 65535 bytes

Does the unserialize have a maximum size?

Here is the line in question within my PHP:

```
$array = unserialize($emails);

// this is the output of $emails (not all of it as it is huge)
string(65535) "a:12134:{i:0;s:29:"12someemail@addr.com ";i:1;s:31:"5myname@email.com "
```

Comment: I don't think it does. You need to provide more info about where your data is coming from

Comment: No, it has not. But guessing from that error message the source of your serialized string had a size limit (TEXT columns are limited to 64K).

Comment: no, they do not (and from what I've [found][1], they can serialize huge strings). They are limited in memory though, which does not seem to be your problem. Could you post the string you try to serialize / unserialize?

[1]: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#79339

Comment: Is this data comming from DB having BLOB/TEXT type?

Comment: not sure why someone gave me a negative i thought my question was fairly clear.. oh well no to worry it isnt the end of the world :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The database field (presumably) that you're storing your serialized data into has a size limit which is exceeded by the length of that string - basically, your data is corrupted.

Comment: the field structure was set to 'TEXT' doh!

Do you recommend that I use a BLOB instead for this field?

Comment: Which btw, besides being too short for your case, is incorrect for another reason too. You can run into problems with character encodings - serialized data should be stored in a binary field.

Comment: @Gav every email address **ought** to be stored in **separate** field - that's the only proper solution!

Comment: @Col you are prob right its a legacy system which i've not built so im just keeping my changes to the system minimal, but i may look into doing that in the future thanks :)

Comment: I have a similar problem, I found out that json_encode is about 40% more space efficient so it is a better solution

Answer (score 3):

You probably store this in a TEXT field in the mysql database. It's maximum size is 65,535 bytes, as in your error.

You can use MEDIUMTEXT, which is the next available.

[image]